# How to get the pagination page ID of a post when viewing it

Tags: wordpress, pagination, blogs

Say I have a blog of 10 items.

Each 5 posts the blog uses pagination to move around so the 10th post is in the 2nd page.

When I view the 2nd post I want to know which page it is in(we know its the 2nd).

Same goes for the 13th post which is in the 3rd page of the blog.

How can I get that page ID?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the page number from the loop variables use this code

`$page = get_query_var('paged');`